# Printing result of an equation

Tags: printing, formulas

```
from math import tan,pi

def polygon_area(sides, length):
     """Returns the area of a regular polygon."""
        sides= 5
        length = 7 
        return (sides *(length **2) /(4 * (tan(pi)/sides)
print ("The area of the polygon is," % polygon_area)
```

I am doing or not doing something very remedial here.  my program is crashing on the print statement.  any thoughts/guidance/nudges appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I see different problems here.

First, you don't close your parentheses correctly on the return line.

Secondly, the print statement is not calling the function properly. You need to pass two arguments.

Lastly (optional fix), in your function you hard code sides and length overriding the arguments.

Solution #1 fixing problems #1 and #2:

```
from math import tan,pi

def polygon_area(sides, length):
    sides = 5
    length = 7 
    return (sides *(length **2) /(4 * (tan(pi)/sides)))
print ("The area of the polygon is,", polygon_area(5, 7))
```

Solution #2 fixing all of the problems

```
from math import tan,pi

def polygon_area(sides, length):
    return (sides *(length **2) /(4 * (tan(pi)/sides)))
print ("The area of the polygon is,", polygon_area(5, 7))
```

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your question.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235